# Scaling centered on certain origin is not working need help :(

Tags: transforms, origin

Trying to scale vertices centered on certain origin where I want.

Unfortunately scaling through the center origin is only available even though I already did 'cursor to selected' and 'origin to cursor'. Need help

[image: This is how I want]

[image: This is the issue having trouble on]

Comment: Sorry, how did you want it - like your first image (scaled in one direction), or the second image (scaled in both directions)?

Comment: First image is what I want. Sorry I think I didn't asked well

Comment: it looks like you're confusing Transform Orientations with Transform Pivot Point (which is the panel on its right)

Comment: Although you can do it with Christopher's answer, it would have worked with the cursor. In the same area where you can switch to _Active Element_ as Christopher suggests, you can also switch to _3D Cursor_ which would have been what you want in the first place, as moonboots' comment indicates.

Comment: Oh yess I find the way. Christopher's answer is based on active element and the way your saying is 3D cursor. The real issue I'm confusing with was the transform pivot point as moonboots says. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your *Transform Pivot Point* to "Active element". Select all the vertices you want to scale, making sure to select the one you don't want to move *last* (so it's the *active* one). Then scale - all the other vertices will scale relative to the active vertex, which can be thought of as somewhat of a "center point".

[image: TransPoint]

NOTE - Don't forget to switch your Transform Pivot back to "Median Point" afterwards, or you'll go absolutely nuts later trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate.